# How to implement react router with raw javascript?(backend .net core mvc)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, asp.net-core-mvc

A web application is already built with CSS,HTML,raw javascript, jquery, ajax, and .net core MVC. The problem with that is there is a _Layout page where there is a renderBody() in which every page gets rendered. For this, whenever I click to visit another page/nav option, the whole website reloads the page comes. As with React, there is react-router by using which the reloading can be prevented. But to implement the same feature with raw JavaScript/ Jquery?Is there any? TIA

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read this article https://medium.com/@fro_g/routing-in-javascript-d552ff4d2921
Or this article https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-build-a-simple-router-in-javascript/

Or You can do the same job of react router be doing this steps
Create page and put layout in it and in the center of this layout add div with id main
and then create all other page in different file and create function that on document ready  read the page url and then  load in the element main the file for this link
And for navigation create function that replace the existing element with other element from file respective for the nav item clicked
It is long process but in the end you will get the same effect as  react router